# Query performance, indexing, and prediction of write time performance hit of a covered index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

## Constraint

I cannot change the query at this time as it's built dynamically by the application and we cannot push code to PROD with a fix today, this week, or even this month. This has to be resolved in the database. That is why I'm evaluating indexes.

We have a table in our database, `CaseHistory`, that has ~10MM rows. Not terrible, but it's a growing pain. The read times are starting to suffer on queries that stem from a search like this:

```
select CaseNumber
    ,isnull(
        (
            select convert(varchar,min(CreationTimeGMT),101)
            from CaseHistory
            where CaseNumber = c.CaseNumber
                and ActionTypeID = 1
        ), 'N/A'
    ) as CreationTimeGMT
    ...
from [Case] c
where CaseNumber in (
    select CaseNumber from CaseHistory
    where ActionTypeID <> 1 and
        CreationTimeGMT >= '10/25/2013'
    ) AND
    CaseNumber in (
        select CaseNumber from CaseHistory
        where ActionTypeID <> 1 and
            CreationTimeGMT <= '10/25/2013'
    )
```

Now, at first glance one might think the sub-query to grab the `CreateionTimeGMT` might be an issue, but I don't believe so because I've analyzed the execution plan. The execution plan for this query used 99% of the processing on a `SEEK` against `IX_CaseHistory_1` (shown below in **Current Indexes**). To further concrete the reason I don't believe it's that sub-query, searches directly against `CaseNumber`, like this:

```
select CaseNumber
    ,isnull(
        (
            select convert(varchar,min(CreationTimeGMT),101)
            from CaseHistory
            where CaseNumber = c.CaseNumber
                and ActionTypeID = 1
        ), 'N/A'
    ) as CreationTimeGMT
    ...
from [Case] c
where CaseNumber = '123456'
```

are **sub** `1s` whereas the aforementioned query runs between `13s` and `15s`.

## Current Indexes

```
IX_CaseHistory (CaseNumber (ASC))
IX_CaseHistory_1 (ActionTypeID (ASC))
IX_CaseHistory_2 (CreationTimeGMT (ASC))
```

So, what I want to do is build a **clustered** covered index on `CaseNumber, ActionTypeID, CreationTimeGMT`. Currently the *clustered* index is on the `IDENTITY PK`.

Why clustered?

Because I want this query to run faster too (which is executed 1,000's of times per day):

```
select  CaseHistoryID
    ,CaseNumber
    ,ActionTypeID
    ,CreationTimeGMT
    ,UserID
    ,Notes
from    CaseHistory
where   CaseNumber = @CaseNumber
order by CreationTimeGMT
```

However, I have one basic concern, **how can I *predict* what kind of hit will this have on write times?**

Comment: +1 for a neat question

Comment: Can you please add the relevant DB tags?

Comment: we'd need to see the query plan to assess your analysis.

Comment: Maybe changing your two IN into a single query might make things faster: select CaseNumber from CaseHistory where ActionTypeID <> 1 group by CaseNumber having min(CreationTimeGMT) < '10/25/2013' and max(CreationTimeGMT) > '10/25/2013'

Comment: @the_lotus, yeah that's a guarantee. I've added the fact that I can't change the query as a constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I predict what kind of hit will this have on write times?

For inserts (I assume that's what you mean by "write"), the main concern when working with a clustered index is *where will the new data be inserted*.  If you usually add values to the *end* of a clustered index (e.g. an Auto-Increment key) then writes should be very fast - it just adds the new record to the end.

In your case, I assume that inserts are *not* sequential, but are randomly placed within the existing data.  In that case you need to consider [*fill factor*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459.aspx), which will determine how much space between existing records will be left open to accept inserts.

The trade-offs for a low fill factor to allow many inserts is higher read times of the non-index columns, since the resulting data may be spread over multiple pages, thus requiring more I/O.  Also more disk space is needed since the table will need to allocate empty space for new inserts (rather than just growing automatically)

I would reduce your fill factor to 80 (meaning leave 20% of the space for new inserts) and regularly reorganize your table to keep some space between records for new data.

Comment: Yes, you're correct that by *write* I do mean `INSERT`. So, if I left the *current* **clustered index**, which is on the `IDENTITY` column, and added the newly covered index, I wouldn't really see an increase in write times? Is the overhead for rebuilding the new covered index during a write just not measurable enough to worry about?

Comment: You can only have one clustered index, so you'd have to _replace_ the current clustered index.

Comment: Understood, but if I simply left it in the current configuration, there would be no real overhead for writing to the data page -- but what about predicting the overhead for rebuilding that newly created covered index when a new record is added?

Comment: With the current clustered index, you're always writing to the end, which is fast, but reads are affected because it has to lookup the key value then go read the data.  Updating the new covered index will depend on the fill factor.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better reworking your sql a bit to begin with,

```
SELECT
        c.[CaseNumber],
        isnull(convert(varchar, min(h.[CreationTimeGMT]), 101), 'N/A'),
        ...
FROM [Case] c
LEFT JOIN [CaseHistory] h ON h.[CaseNumber] = c.[CaseNumber]
GROUP BY
        c.[CaseNumber]
WHERE
        h.[ActionTypeID] = 1
    AND
        EXISTS(
            SELECT
                    h.[CaseNumber]
            FROM [CaseHistory] h
            WHERE
                    h.[CaseNumber] = c.[CaseNumber]
                AND
                    h.[ActionTypeID] <> 1
                AND
                    h.[CreationTimeGMT] BETWEEN '10/25/2013' AND '10/25/2013');
```

once you do that, you can see the subquer(ies/y) in the where clause are a more complicated proposition.

I'd suspect that for `CaseHistory` your clustered index should remain on `CaseHistoryID`, since its unique. I'd be tempted to create a covering index on

```
`CaseNumber`, `ActionType`, `CreationTimeGMT`
```

but, because of the "`<> 1`" in the subquery, I'd also try flipping the conditions e.g.

```
                    h.[CreationTimeGMT] BETWEEN '10/25/2013' AND '10/25/2013'
                AND
                    h.[ActionTypeID] <> 1);
```

and add this covering index too

```
`CaseNumber`, `CreationTimeGMT`, `ActionType`
```

As ever, the key for performance is to get the most selective conditions first.

I cannot predict the actual costs on your database, since I don't have your data, statistics, environment etc...

Comment: +1 because I don't disagree that the query is atrocious. In fact, we've got a CC in to fix how that works and I'll consider your approach when rebuilding that code. Now, as for the covered index, I was actually working through a similar idea (adding `ActionType` to the end of it), and then will modify the query to leverage the `BETWEEN` and `AND` like you have there when I can rebuild it. For now, you would also agree that the covered index will at least change the amount of time it takes to query right? How about *predicting* the write time overhead for that new index?

Comment: @neoistheone, real but probably insiginificant. How often are you inserting rows?

Comment: It's ~35% of the transaction load against that table probably.